# Windows - Win2k8 Server goes into Sleep mode - unwarranted

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

WIndows Server 2008

I have sleep set to NEVER everywhere I can find. Still, server will go to sleep (and I have to use Ctl-Alt-Del to re-start) after only a few unattended minutes. I've changed Screen Saver, Power Options - everything I can think of - still sleeps regularly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Put this on Serverfault?

Comment: Is server sleeping or hibernating?  Have you checked Power settings in the BIOS?

Comment: Sleeping (I believe) - I need to hit Ctl-Alt-Del and then re-login. I;ve looked in the BIOS, don't see anything related to sleep/suspend - is this something in particular I should look for?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following two commands, in order, from a command prompt:

powercfg -h on

powercfg -h off